# Feature selection pipeline: X has a different shape than during fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, random-forest

I am trying to make a pipeline that selects 250 best features from a set and then fits a Random Forest Regressor on these features. Then I wish to use this to make predictions about fresh data X_fresh. To do this, I first select the 250 best features from the fresh data as well using the line `X_fresh=X_fresh[:,selector.get_support(indices=True)]`. However, after running the full code, this  yields the error "X has a different shape than during fitting".

It seems that when I fit the pipeline it does not automatically transform the values in X_train to include only the 250 best features.

How can I correct this? The full code is given below:

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline

selector=SelectKBest(f_regression)
pipeline=Pipeline(steps=[('selector', selector),('regressor', RandomForestRegressor())])

estimator=pipeline.set_params(selector__k=250,regressor__n_estimators=175).fit(X_train, y_train)

X_fresh=X_fresh[:,selector.get_support(indices=True)]

#Use it to predict the target values of the test data set
y_pred=estimator.predict(X_fresh)
```

Comment: Because Xfresh is new data that I want to make predictions on. So I have to keep only the 'good' features of it . It has nothing to do with Xtrain

Answer (score 0):

You're performing a transformation to `X_fresh` that you are not performing to `X_train`.  Your pipeline expects the input data from `X_fresh` to be the same shape as `X_train`.  By doing this `selector` transformation before the pipeline you're changing the shape of `X_fresh` so that it no longer matches `X_train`.

Since `selector` is already a part of the pipeline this code is unnecessary:

```
X_fresh=X_fresh[:,selector.get_support(indices=True)
```

When you call `y_pred=estimator.predict(X_fresh)` the `selector` step will run as a part of the pipeline so there is not need to call that step independently.  This is one of the benefits of using a pipeline to begin with.  When you do call the `estimator` make sure `X_fresh` matches the shape of `X_train` since that's what the trained pipeline would be expecting.

A pipeline works by chaining steps of a model together.  In your pipeline you have a feature selection step, `selector`, and a regression step, `regressor`.  When you call the `fit()` method on your pipeline the input data, `X_train` is first transformed by `selector` to have the 250 best features and then the transformed data is being fed into the `regressor` step to train the regression model.

When you call `predict()` on your pipeline the new data you feed in will perform those same steps, so there is no need to perform any step from the pipeline independently.

Prior to fitting your pipeline you should get `X_train.shape` to determine how many columns are in `X_train`.  After you fit `estimator` you have to make sure `X_fresh` has the same columns as `X_train`.  Then when you call predict on your `estimator` the pipeline will automatically perform the feature selection and produce predictions.

Comment: OK. I understand that but shouldn't the fit already transform the X_train data to include only the 250 best features?

Comment: Basically, I have tried to run .transform on the pipeline but it cannot execute this command since the RandomForestRegressor does not have a transform method. I do not know how to transform the data to keep only the best features, directly using the pipeline.

Comment: Updated my answer with a little background information about how pipelines work.